# How can I find out why my "Ad Hoc" build for iPhone will not install?

Tags: iphone, itunes, xcode4.2

Following the instructions at [MusicalGeometry.com](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1237), I've archived and created the .ipa file.  However, whenever I try to install it to my iPhone through iTunes, it gets about 3/4ths of the way done before it stops and tells me the app failed to install.  How can I go about finding out why it failed to install?

I'm using xCode 4.2

Thanks~

**EDIT**

I am trying to install an app that I currently have on the market.  I do have a valid developer account, and the app is code signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is whether the device you are trying to install to is added to a list of development devices in the Provisioning Portal.

Then please check if your device is in a list of devices your provisioning profile supports (Review your Ad Hoc profile in Provisioning Portal).

Here's how you can do it:

1. Go to Provisioning Portal, navigate to Provisioning -> Distribution

   [image: Step 1]
2. Edit your Ad Hoc profile and make sure your target devices are selected:

   [image: Step 2]

Comment: Well I definitely know that my iPhone is in my provisioning list because I use it for debugging.  However, I'm not sure what you mean about the ad hoc profile in the provisioning portal.  This may be my issue.  Can you explain how I would get to that?

Comment: @James I've updated my answer with instructions how to do it.

Comment: Excellent!  This was my exact issue.  I had no Ad Hoc profile.  Thank you.  It installs now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a paid developer account and is the app codesigned?